# Biggest value in bar chart does not appear

Tags: javascript, bar-chart

I have a bar chart that I have scripted and am loading values in through my json file.  All values appear through labels except for my highest value (60). What can I do to get my 60 label to appear in my chart?

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>CS50C Week11</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="margin-top: 50px; padding:auto">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" ></canvas>
      </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

data.json

```
[25, 30, 40, 50, 35, 20, 45, 60, 55, 50]
```

script.js

```
try {
  // Load data from JSON file
  fetch('data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Initialize canvas element
      const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      if (!canvas) {
        throw new Error('Canvas element not found');
      }
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // Set chart properties
      let chartWidth = 500;
      let chartHeight = 500;
      const barSpacing = 10;
      const barWidth = (chartWidth - (data.length - 1) * barSpacing) / data.length;
      const maxValue = Math.max(...data);
      const labelFont = '16px Arial';
      const valueFont = '12px Arial';
      const labelColor = '#333';
      const valueColor = '#999';

      // Draw bars and labels
        data.forEach((value, index) => {
        const x = index * (barWidth + barSpacing);
        const y = chartHeight - (value / maxValue) * chartHeight;
        const height = (value / maxValue) * chartHeight;

        // Draw bar
        ctx.fillStyle = '#66a';
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, barWidth, height);

        // Draw label
        ctx.font = labelFont;
        ctx.fillStyle = labelColor;
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillText(` ${index + 1}`, x + barWidth / 2, chartHeight + 20);

        // Draw value
        ctx.font = valueFont;
        ctx.fillStyle = valueColor;
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillText(value, x + barWidth / 2, y - 10);


      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
```

I have tried adding this if condition in my Draw Label section of my JS

```
 ctx.textAlign = 'center';              
if (index === data.length - 1) {
        // Adjust x-coordinate for last bar label
        x += barWidth / 2;
      }
```

so that way it only manipulates x under that condition, but doing so makes my bar furthest to the right disappear (in addition to my 60 bar already being gone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some space at the top of the bars for the labels. You could define a `barMaxHeight = chartHeight-20` and use that to compute each bar's height on the chart:

```js
const data = [25, 30, 40, 50, 35, 20, 45, 60, 55, 50];
// Initialize canvas element
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
if (!canvas) {
    throw new Error('Canvas element not found');
}
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Set chart properties
let chartWidth = canvas.offsetWidth;
let chartHeight = canvas.offsetHeight;
let barMaxHeight = chartHeight-20;
const barSpacing = 10;
const barWidth = (chartWidth - (data.length - 1) * barSpacing) / data.length;
const maxValue = Math.max(...data);
const labelFont = '16px Arial';
const valueFont = '12px Arial';
const labelColor = '#333';
const valueColor = '#999';

// Draw bars and labels
data.forEach((value, index) => {
    const x = index * (barWidth + barSpacing);
    const y = chartHeight - (value / maxValue) * barMaxHeight;
    const height = (value / maxValue) * barMaxHeight;

    // Draw bar
    ctx.fillStyle = '#66a';
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, barWidth, height);

    // Draw label
    ctx.font = labelFont;
    ctx.fillStyle = labelColor;
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(` ${index + 1}`, x + barWidth / 2, chartHeight + 20);

    // Draw value
    ctx.font = valueFont;
    ctx.fillStyle = valueColor;
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(value, x + barWidth / 2, y - 10);
});
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 50px; padding:auto">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid gray" ></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This helped and solve my issue.